# How to secure connection to Azure Portal from Home

Tags: azure, azureportal

We would like to secure the connection to the Azure Portal from home because we are login every day to Azure Portal with very high privileged accounts.

We have already activated the MFA but we are not sure if it ’s enough and would like to add more security.

Does Azure have any VPN or certificate to allow only our company computers to login to our Azure Portail?

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are looking for is [Continuous access evaluation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/concept-continuous-access-evaluation). With that your company can set it up so that only the IP addresses of the company owned computers are allowed to access the tenant. It is currently in public preview.

According [to the announcement](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-active-directory-identity/continuous-access-evaluation-in-azure-ad-is-now-in-public/ba-p/1751704) it looks like Azure is not available yet but is coming in the future.